# Get selecteditem from listbox using MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM in this project, I have a listbox which bind to a collection of Customers. I want to create an event to navigate a detailsPage using id of the elementselected:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" x:Name="state_list" SelectionChanged="state_list_SelectionChanged">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="selectionchanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding stateSelectedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"  />

                 </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding nom}" />
                        <!--TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbCount}" /-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I can't figure out how to get the selected item to add it to the uri and then use it to get data. An example or tutorial would be helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

I would create a "SelectedCustomer" property in the ViewModel (next to you Customers property)  and bind it to the SelectedItem. Then, on the setter of that property you can navigate to your desired page. This way you eliminate the messy events and command.

```
<ListBox x:Name="state_list 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

...

```
public Customer SelectedCustomer
{
  get
  {
    return _selectedCustomer;
  }
  set
  {
    if (value != null)
    {
    _selectedCustomer = value;
    //Navigate to your page here, either with Navigator class or any other mechanism you have in place for changing content on screen
    }
  } 

}
```

Comment: that and make sure "SelectedItem" uses TwoWay binding

Comment: I used this method before, but it seems like it has side effects - for example, you're incorporating phone-specific logic into your view model, so it's no longer as portable. Second, you're not extablishing the contract that, when you set the SelectedCustomer, you'll go to a new page which has the customer details

Comment: And you need to check for null too

Comment: @vidalsasoon, you need the TwoWay binding only if you are planning to update the selection in the View based on the ViewModel. since the original question did not mention that, I did not include it.

Comment: Updated the code to check for null. You could write your navigation method in such a way to be disconnected.

Comment: where did that _selectedCustomer come from?

Answer (score 1):

AlexDrenea gives you a good way of binding SelectedItem to a property on your viewmodel.  If you are wanting to navigate based on this in an MVVM architecture, I would suggest using messaging to get it done.

I cover this in a blog post I did a while back, but the short summary of doing this within MVVMLight, is to create a Navigator class that sits at the application level.

```
public class Navigator
    {

        private PhoneApplicatoinFrame RootFrame;

        public Navigator(PhoneApplicationFrame frame)
        {
            RootFrame = frame;
            RegisterMessages();
        }

        private void RegisterMessages()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<ShowTrackerMessage>(this, ShowTracker);
        }

        private void ShowTracker(ShowTrackerMessage msg)
        {
            RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/ItemLocationCompassView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }

}
```

Then, as part of your application start-up, create it and pass it a reference to your RootFrame:

```
    private static Navigator _navigator;
    public static Navigator Nav
    {
        get { return _navigator; }
    }
```

...

```
_navigator = new Navigator(this.RootFrame);
```

Then, you have a couple choices on how you send the Navigation message.

Option 1:  In your ViewModel, hook into the PropertyChanged event (part of INotifyPropertyChanged), and send the appropriate message when your SelectedItem property changes.

Option 2:  Tie into the SelectionChanged event of your ListBox.  I use the MVVMLight's EventToCommand to send that event to a RelayCommand in my ViewModel, then react appropriately to send the message to the Navigator object.

I cover this in more detail at:  http://www.smartchitecture.com/?p=27

Comment: if i really unterstand your idea, i have to create a navigator class and define the target page for each time i need to realize this action ! which isn't  good way no?

Comment: Besides that, i want to recover that id and put it in another web request to get data..i know that i have to use onNavigatedTO for that but how can i pass it on the detailsViewModel.. ! thanks :)

Comment: You might be able to define the target page as a command parameter, and pass that to the Navigator, which moves your navigation to a more declarative place. I like my approach, though, because all of my navigation is centralized, so if I have to rearrange things, or rename things, I only have one place to go to change them.